# Angular: How can I pass a variable in FormBuilder.group()?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, scope, angular-components

Provided a variable to the Validators.max() method, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Here the implementation of the model:

*maximums.model.ts*

```
export class Maximums {
   id: number;
   max_hr_1: number; 
   max_hr_2: number;
)
```

Here the implementation of the service:

*maximums.service.ts*

```
export class MaximumsService {

  (...)

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  listMaxs(): Observable<Maximums> {
    return this.http.get<Maximums>('http://localhost:8081/maximums/list'); 
  }  
}
```

Here the implementation of the component:

*activity-form.component.ts*

```
(...)
export class ActivityFormComponent implements OnInit{

maximums: Maximums;
max_hr_1: number; 
max_hr_2: number; 

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private maximumsService: MaximumsService){ }

ngOnInit(): void {

   this.maximums = new Maximums();
   this.getMaxs();

   fg: FormGroup;

   this.fg = this.fb.group({
   hr_1: [null, Validators.max(this.max_hr_1)],
   hr_2: [null, Validators.max(this.max_hr_2)],
   });
}

getMaxs(): void {
    this.maximumsService.listMaxs().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.maximums = data;
        this.max_hr_1 = this.maximums.max_hr_1; 
        this.max_hr_2 = this.maximums.max_hr_2;
      },
      (erro) => {
        console.log(erro);
      }
    );
  }


(...)
```

Here the implementation of the template:

*activity-form.component.html*

```
(...)

<form name="form" [formGroup]="fg" #f="ngForm">
   <input matInput min="1" type="number" formControlName="hr_1" />
   <mat-error *ngIf="fg.controls['hr_1'].hasError('max')">Maximum is {{max_hr_1}}</mat-error>

   <input matInput min="1" type="number" formControlName="hr_2" />
   <mat-error *ngIf="fg.controls['hr_2'].hasError('max')">Maximum is {{max_hr_2}}</mat-error>
</form>

(...)
```

> Did not work:
> `Validators.max(this.max_hr_1)`

> Did not work:
> `Validators.max(this.maximums.max_hr_1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the form creation into the `subscribe`:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.maximums = new Maximums();
   this.getMaxs();
}

getMaxs(): void {
 this.maximumsService.listMaxs().subscribe(
   (data) => {
     this.maximums = data;
     this.max_hr_1 = this.maximums.max_hr_1; 
     this.max_hr_2 = this.maximums.max_hr_2;
     this.createForm();
   },
   (error) => console.log(error)}
  );
}

private createForm(): void {
  this.fg = this.fb.group({
     hr_1: [null, Validators.max(this.max_hr_1)],
     hr_2: [null, Validators.max(this.max_hr_2)],
  });
}
```

Or just add the validators right after you get the response from the `http` call like the following:

```js
getMaxs(): void {
 this.maximumsService.listMaxs().subscribe(
   (data) => {
     this.maximums = data;
     this.max_hr_1 = this.maximums.max_hr_1; 
     this.max_hr_2 = this.maximums.max_hr_2;
     
     this.fg.get('hr_1').addValidators(Validators.max(this.max_hr_1));
     this.fg.get('hr_2').addValidators(Validators.max(this.max_hr_2));
   },
   (error) => console.log(error)}
  );
}
```

Comment: The first solution (move the form creation into the subscribe) worked, thank you very much!

Comment: The validators after get the response from the http returns the error ..."Property 'addValidators' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'"... The my local Angular version different maybe?